# How to insert custom class item to map C++

Tags: c++, dictionary, iterator

I have a class, how can i add one object of this class to map, and find it by id?

**Class code:**

```
class Client {
    int FileDescriptor, Id, cryptcode;
    unsigned char CustomData[256];

    void PrepareClient()
    {
        // init code
    }
  public:
    AnticheatClient (int fd, int id, int crypt_code)
    {
        FileDescriptor = fd;
        Id = id;
        cryptcode = crypt_code;
        PrepareCrypt();
    }

    void OwnCryptEncrypt(unsigned char* data, int len)
    {
 //...
    }

    void OwnCryptDecrypt(unsigned char* data, int len)
    {
 //...
    }
};

std::map<int, Client> ClientTable;

int main()
{
 int id = 1;
 Client c(1, id, 1);
 // how can i add this client to map and how can i find it by id?
}
```

I tried so many example codes but not with custom class so they didn't work.
Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "they didn't work"?

Comment: [StackOverflow is not a Language Tutorial.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/134609/142865)  For good, peer-reviewed learning resources, check out [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](http://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/241536) and our [C++-FAQ Tag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b-faq)

Comment: Please copy-paste your error message. Also your attempted  code in main.

Answer (score 1):

For adding a `Client` with key=10:

```
ClientTable[10] = Client(1, id, 1);
```

For find an element with key=10:

```
std::map<int, Client>::iterator it = ClientTable.find(10);
if (it != ClientTable.end()) {
    int key = it->first;
    Client c = it->second;
}
```

You can also use:

```
Client c = ClientTable[10];
```

but calling `operator[]` is not `const`. So, that is most probably not what you want to use if you just want to find an element.

Answer (score 0):

1) "*how can i add one object of this class to map?*"

```
ClientTable[id] = c;
```

Well, technically, it adds a **copy** of the object to the map.

2) "*and find it by id?*"

```
Client lookerUpper = ClientTable[id];
```